# Fillter multiple fields in delphi

Tags: database, ms-access, filter, delphi-2010

How can one make use of a filter to filter multiple fields in my database.

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to work

```
dmData.tbl1.Filter := ('Gender =' + QuotedStr(sGender)) AND ('Grade =' + Quoted(edtGrade.Text));
```

So what I want for the program to do, for example, is display those who are male in the 10th grade.

Comment: Knowing nothing about your data and and the used criteria, maybe you are comparing NULL fields with empty strings? `aField is NULL`

Comment: *"Doesn't seem to work"* - meaning, this gives a compilation error. It's not valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot

```
dmData.tbl1.Filter := ('Gender = ' + QuotedStr(sGender) + 'AND Grade = '+ QuotedStr(edtGrade.Text));
```

Comment: Work for (DBF) dBase Ttable and TQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dmData.tbl1.Filter := '(Gender = ''' + sGender + ''') AND (Grade = ''' + edtGrade.Text + ''')';
```

Or:

```
dmData.tbl1.Filter := '(Gender = ' + AnsiQuotedStr(sGender, '''') + ') AND (Grade = ' + AnsiQuotedStr(edtGrade.Text, '''') + ')';
```

Comment: I tried the second one, but what it does is it only shows 1 out of a few possible records that should be shown and the first one did work either.

Comment: The fact that it showed any records at all means the filter worked. Maybe your fields are case sensitive and the missing records did not actually match the case of the filter? Or maybe there is whitespace present that you are not accounting for? Since you have not shown the relevant record data, or the values of `sGender` and `edtGrade.Text`, I can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the whole syntax inside the quotation marks,
it should be like that

```
dmData.tbl1.Filter := 'Gender = ' + QuotedStr(sGender) + ' AND ' + 'Grade = ' + Quoted(edtGrade.Text);
```